# How to detect new fingerprint is added in phone with flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, dart-pub

l am using biometric to auth users in my app,

Is their a way in flutter to detect if new finger have being added in phone ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on the platform and how exactly you want to do this.

On Android, when you create a key you can specify that it is invalidated if additional fingerprints are enrolled using `KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder`'s `setInvalidatedByBiometricEnrollment` function. However, there is a caveat with this - it only works with keys that require active authentication, and the only way to find out that a key has been invalidated is to try authenticating it... which would throw a `KeyPermanentlyInvalidatedException` if this were the case, but would probably open the authentication dialog if it is still valid which might not be what you want in terms of user experience.

On iOS, it's a little more straightforward as you can check the domain state

```
let context = LAContext()
if context.canEvaluatePolicy(.deviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, error: nil {
  if let newDomainState = context.evaluatedPolicyDomainState {
    if newDomainState.base64EncodedString() != oldDomainStateString {
      // doesn't match so have to update oldDomainStateString (wherever that is saved)
      // and do whatever else.
    } else {
      // domains still match, fingerprint still the same.
    }
  } else {
    // can't get the policy for some reason. Hopefully shouldn't happen
    // since we're checking canEvaluatePolicy
  }
}
```

However, there's another issue - neither of those APIs are exposed directly through any plugin that I'm aware of anyways, so you're going to have to write the native code yourself. Honestly this probably isn't the worst thing anyways since you should have a pretty good understanding of this stuff or do a very good job of reading any 3rd-party libraries you use for it, but it does mean that you'll have to have a good understanding of flutter's platform channels, as well as both iOS/swift and Android/kotlin code & security APIS to be able to implement it.

Comment: Thanks  @rmtmckenzie , just to make sure i got it right let me explain to you, what i understand from above ,, 
I will continue use local_auth for cabality of biometric auth as usual, but i will extend service for check if fingerprint is changed in each platform differently.

for IOS; will send notification to flutter (may be true/false) through platform channel that finger have changed or still the same as you have show, continue to auth use or disable based on my desire flow .

for Android;

Comment: I create a key as a reference during auth, and check if if finger have changed or not if changed set invalid ( finger have change) , and notify flutter framework through platfom channel .

Comment: @DanfordKija yes that is correct. The only issue that might come up is as I mentioned; I don't think you can do the "check" on android unless you trigger an authentication (which means the OS will display the finger popup if no fingerprints have been added, which might not be ideal). I could be incorrect about that or it might be possible to pass a set of options to the authentication such that it doesn't trigger a popup, but you'll have to investigate that yourself. Any solution will definitely require platform-specific code for both ios and android though.

Comment: I am investigate it right now,

I will notify you, if it work out in both platform and give a thumbs up as a solution to my question.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: thanks, this solve my issue. and learning a lot .
some notes to pass through:
  - https://github.com/Kijacode/security-samples,
  - http,s://github.com/OWASP/owasp-mastg
  - i created it plugin on this, i will make it plublic in the  future